# Issue with redrawing premultiplied alpha bitmap with Win32 GDI

Tags: c++, windows, gdi, premultiplied-alpha

I am building a setup program that has a back button and a next button, typical for setup programs.
However, I seem to be having an problem, while the initial draw works, if I change the button bitmap to a activated one, then switch back to the deactivated one, it seems like the alpha layer is getting added on and on.

Better representation of what is happening:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Deactivated state. | [image: Deactivated State] |
| After I click the Next button, bringing me to the next page, button switches to a activated bitmap. | [image: Activated State] |
| If I click the Back button, going back to the first page, I get this instead of the first state I expected. | [image: DeactivatedState after going from activated] |

Here's my `WM_PAINT` that draws the back button

```cpp
InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, 1); // Clear the window after a button state change requiring redraw
HBRUSH hBrushBtn;
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
hBrushBtn = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
BITMAP          bitmap01;
PAINTSTRUCT     ps;
HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hBackBtn, &ps);
FillRect(hdc, &rc, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1)); // Attempt #1 at fixing the bug, it did not work.

PremultiplyAlpha(hdc, hBackBtnTmpImg); // Premultiplied alpha function call

HDC hdcMem01 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HGDIOBJ oldBitmap01 = SelectObject(hdcMem01, hBackBtnTmpImg);

GetObjectW(hBackBtnTmpImg, sizeof(bitmap01), &bitmap01);

BLENDFUNCTION bf = { AC_SRC_OVER, 0, 255, AC_SRC_ALPHA };
AlphaBlend(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap01.bmWidth, bitmap01.bmHeight, hdcMem01, 0, 0, bitmap01.bmWidth, bitmap01.bmHeight, bf); // Paint the image

SelectObject(hdcMem01, oldBitmap01);
DeleteDC(hdcMem01);
EndPaint(hBackBtn, &ps);
```

And here's the function that premultiplies the bitmap

```cpp
void PremultiplyAlpha(HDC hDC, HBITMAP hBmp)
{
    BITMAP bm = { 0 };
    GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bminfoheader;
    ::ZeroMemory(&bminfoheader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    bminfoheader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bminfoheader.biWidth = bm.bmWidth;
    bminfoheader.biHeight = bm.bmHeight;
    bminfoheader.biPlanes = 1;
    bminfoheader.biBitCount = 32;
    bminfoheader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    HDC windowDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    LPBYTE pBitData = (LPBYTE) ::LocalAlloc(LPTR, bm.bmWidth * bm.bmHeight * sizeof(DWORD));
    if (pBitData == NULL) return;
    LPBYTE pData = pBitData;

    GetDIBits(windowDC, hBmp, 0, bm.bmHeight, pData, (BITMAPINFO*)&bminfoheader, DIB_RGB_COLORS); // load pixel info

    for (int y = 0; y < bm.bmHeight; y++) {
        BYTE *pPixel = (BYTE *)pData + bm.bmWidth * 4 * y;
        for (int x = 0; x < bm.bmWidth; x++) {
            pPixel[0] = pPixel[0] * pPixel[3] / 255;
            pPixel[1] = pPixel[1] * pPixel[3] / 255;
            pPixel[2] = pPixel[2] * pPixel[3] / 255;
            pPixel += 4;
        }
    }

    SetDIBits(windowDC, hBmp, 0, bm.bmHeight, pData, (BITMAPINFO*)&bminfoheader, DIB_RGB_COLORS); // save the pixel info for later manipulation
    ::LocalFree(pBitData);
}
```

I tried my best to resolve this by making three iterations of the function that is supposed to do the same thing, all of which failed.

Comment: It looks like you are premultiplying alpha of the same bitmap on each iteration, corrupting it. The whole point of premultiplied alpha is to perform multiplication in advance to save computational power each time when drawing it.